# Can I combine upsert and remove?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDb beginner here.

I am trying to match a request and responses in a stream of message. They have a correlation id, but I do not know in which order I will receive requests and responses.
So I would like to combine upsert and remove functionality in one atomic call:

```
if ( <collection has document A with key X> ) 
   return and remove doc A
else 
   insert doc B with key X
```

So, combining upsert and findOneAndDelete. Can this be done? Or would I need to do an upsert to set a "deleted" flag and then clean the "deleted=true" documents later?
But it looks like we have

Comment: you can do findOneAndDelete, check the response, and if it was found and delete do nothing, else send an insert command. i dont think you can combine those in 1 command, but why you worry about this? send 2 it will be fast anyways.

Comment: Thanks. I think this would fail in the concurrent case - different application instances might process the two messages at the same time, so they would need to do findOneAndDelete, then upsert, then possibly delete, if the upsert ended up being an update. 
I would prefer to let MongoDb handle the concurrency manangement, if possible?

For perspective, I have to support data rates of 1000 messages per second for some hours.